# Regex to split apart text. Special case for parentheses with spaces in them

Tags: sql, regex, looker

I am trying to split a field by delimiter in LookML. This field either follows the format of:

1. Managers (AE)
2. Managers (AE - MM)

I was able to split to first case using this

```
sql: case
      when rlike (${user_role_name}, '^.*[\\(\\)].*$') then split_part(${user_role_name}, ' ', -1)
```

However, I haven't been able to get the 2nd case to do the same. It's in a case statement so I am going to add another when statement, but am not able to figure out the regex for parentheses that contains spaces.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Do a replace first to remove the spaces, then you can run same condition.

Comment: what's your expected result?

Comment: @PepeNO for case #1 it would be (AE) and for case #2 it would be (AE - MM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "split" the string, I think you mean you want to extract the part in parentheses, right?

I would do this using a regex substring method. You didn't mention what warehouse you're using, and the syntax will vary a little, but on snowflake that would look like:

```sql
regexp_substr(${user_role_name}, '\\([^)]*\\)')
```

So, for example, with the inputs you gave:

```sql
select regexp_substr('Managers (AE)', '\\([^)]*\\)')
union all
select regexp_substr('Managers (AE - MM)', '\\([^)]*\\)')
```

| result |
| --- |
| (AE) |
| (AE - MM) |

Comment: Wouldn't just this work for everything inside of literal parens, inclusive: `'\\(.*\\)'`

Comment: These both worked great. Was overthinking with the case statements. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Gary_W yes, they're equivalent if the input string only has a single matching pair of parentheses. If there is more than one closing paren (e.g., `Managers (AE) (MM)`, my pattern will only match the first pair (`(AE)`); because of greedy matching, your pattern will match both (`(AE) (MM)`).